# How to add text to NSTableView

Tags: cocoa

I made a Cocoa application that has an NSTableView, an NSTextField, and an NSButton. The user enters text into the text field and clicks the button. When the user does this, I want the text in the textfield to be placed in the NSTableView. I find that I can't even bind an IBOutlet to a cell in the NSTableView. What should be done?

Answer (score 1):

The Model-View-Controller pattern, which is used extensively in Cocoa is your friend here.

What you need to do is to bind the NSTableView to an array (The model). Then configure the button so that a click tells the controller to add the content of the text field to the array and if the bindings are set up correctly the NSTableView (The View) will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you need to do is make a class, AppController for instance which will be your data source and the delegate of the NSTableView. So you need the following.

1. Two IBOutlets (one for the NSTextField and one for the NSTableView)
2. An IBAction for the NSButton.

Make those connections in Interface Builder.
Remember to use the mandatory delegate methods (there are two of them) so you can add the data from your data source (usually a collection class..an array, dictionary...etc.